# Getting permission to the external storage (file_provider plugin)

Tags: flutter

I'm having some problems getting permissions to the external storage on android devices with flutter.

When I try to create a directory in my external storage I get this error (I've changed the directory just for this example. In my own project the directory name is different):

```
I/flutter (12727): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12727): The following FileSystemException was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (12727): Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/com.domain.bundle' (OS Error: Permission denied,
I/flutter (12727): errno = 13)
I/flutter (12727):
```

I've already added
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
to the manifest file and rebuild the entire project. What else can I try?

Also just listing all the files in the external storage gives the same permission error.

Hope to hear!

Comment: What is android version on your phone?

Comment: I have Android 8.0.0 on my phone. But it needs to work across the board so to speak.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? And can you check if the permission is enabled in the Settings of your app?

Comment: I'm not using a plugin. I'm using path_provider for a path to the extended storage and just try to create a directory at the given location

Comment: Can you check if the permission is enabled (allowed) in Settings?

Comment: I get the same issue with Android 10, please tell how you fixed it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Beside needing to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

You also need **Runtime Request Permission**, by using [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions) package:

```
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

PermissionStatus permissionResult = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission. WriteExternalStorage);
if (permissionResult == PermissionStatus.authorized){
  // code of read or write file in external storage (SD card)
}
```

Note:

1. when running `SimplePermissions.requestPermission` for the **First Time**， app will popup a window, you **MUST** click `ALLOW`:

[image]

to give permission.

2. If  you already clicked `DENY`, then uninstall debug app and re-debug it to install and fix this -> trigger the popup window and give you chance to click `ALLOW`.

Comment: this is not working and the error donot go off. please help me . I'm using API 28 android emulator

Comment: Do you get permission denied?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please fix it

Comment: I would need to see your code. please make a new question with a sample code on the usage. Best is if you have basic helloworld app with permissions.

Comment: I have error about
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.1.0+1\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip    


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
The plugin connectivity_macos could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: SimplePermissions plugin not working and no longer supported.

Comment: I am trying to access /storage/emulated/ directory but getting error "Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)" while i have granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Simple permission is not working. when I run my app in debug mode is works well but when I build APK then it's show me a Error: Getter not found: 'ReadExternalStorage'.
    bool result = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage);

Comment: this is no longer supported. please use permission handler in sted of simple permission

Answer (score 16):

In Android Q, this Error will be resolved by adding the Following Lines in AndroidManifest file:

```xml
 <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Answer (score 7):

please use package permission_handler to request permission. 
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler 
https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

...

void _showFilesinDir({Directory dir}) {
    dir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
    .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
      print(entity.path);
    });
  }

...

onTap: () async{
            Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);

            var systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
            _showFilesinDir(dir: systemTempDir);

            final myDir = new Directory('/sdcard');
            myDir.exists().then((isThere) {
              isThere ? _showFilesinDir(dir: myDir) : print('non-existent');
            });

          }
...
```

and the result of emulator look like this:

```
I/flutter (19980): /data/user/0/xxx.login_challenge/code_cache/flutter_engine <br>
I/flutter (19980): /data/user/0/xxx.login_challenge/code_cache/login_challengeMSBLSX <br>
...
I/flutter (19980): /sdcard/Android <br>
```

Comment: I am trying to access /storage/emulated/ directory but getting error "Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)" while i have granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh, could you post reproduce code to a new question. if you use Android 10, you need https://medium.com/@sriramaripirala/android-10-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-da8b630a89df

Comment: "Please use"  - why ?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to have this in your

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.yyy">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

Then add permission_handler package to your project [Permission_handler - pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Then in your code you can do something like this:

```
final permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
if (permissionStatus.isDenied) {
    // Here just ask for the permission for the first time
    await Permission.storage.request();

    // I noticed that sometimes popup won't show after user press deny
    // so I do the check once again but now go straight to appSettings
    if (permissionStatus.isDenied) {
        await openAppSettings();
    }
} else if (permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    // Here open app settings for user to manually enable permission in case 
    // where permission was permanently denied
    await openAppSettings();
} else {
    // Do stuff that require permission here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Android 6.0 and higher, if the app has features that need Dangerous permission ([list of dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#perm-groups)), it has to ask the permission(s) explicitly (look at the images [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview))

You added the permission to Manifest file, this is not enough, you also need to implement Runtime requests for your permissions also.

I checked on the Flutter repository, it seems they are working on a plugin for this. Here is [their discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/685).

Answer (score 3):

Possible Solution:

I also got the same error (in Android 10 Device) even after adding the permissions

then I, **manually uninstalling** the Flutter App from the device,

and rerun it.

NOTE: make sure after the installation, allow the **storage permission** from the app settings.

It works for me after struggling for hours (I don't know why this solution works)

Answer (score 3):

in my case, I am using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
just change the version of the plugin from
file_picker: ^4.6.1 to file_picker: ^5.2.6 and its working fine.

Comment: file_picker: ^4.6.1 was working for android < 33. But  file_picker: ^5.2.6  did the job for android 33, "also flutter clean" needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you guys just need to add media permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
```

just add these files in manifest
internal, external permission has for older versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

can use run time request permission provided by **permission_handler** package like this:

```
await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
```

and To ensure that correct permission is granted use this sample code:

```
ServiceStatus serviceStatus = await 
PermissionHandler().checkServiceStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
if (serviceStatus.value == 1){
// permission is granted
}
```

Comment: I suppose your solution uses a plugin and you didn't mention it