# How to create a widget when button is pressed (camera)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a camera preview 500x500 and I tried to add a photo under the camera prewiev when the button is pressed... but I failed. 
I know I have use path image for displaying pic, but it can be ready only after pressing the button.
Does anyone knows simple solution?

Here is my code:

```
Future<void> intializeCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final firstCamera = cameras.first;
    controller = CameraController(firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.high);
    initializeControllerFuture = controller.initialize();
    setState(() {
      isCameraReady = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    intializeCamera();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      controller != null
          ? initializeControllerFuture = controller.initialize()
          : null;
    }
  }

  var path = "";
  void takePic() async {
    try {
      await initializeControllerFuture;
      path = join(
        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );
      await controller.takePicture(path);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
              future: initializeControllerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 500,
                    height: 500,
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio:
                          controller.value.aspectRatio, 
                      child: CameraPreview(controller),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
             RaisedButton(onPressed),
          // here I want to add a small container (with taken picture)
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you grant external storage permission yet?

Comment: Not sure (possibly not, because I don't know this is)

Comment: You have to grant external storage permission first to save your file to android storage. Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin/50571167