# Request write permission for SD Card

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to write data to the SD card for android using the [permission_handler package](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) but it seems that PermissionGroup.storage only request permission for internal storage. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

This is the my code for requesting permission:

```
Future<bool> _checkPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.storage.status;
    print(permission);
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And this is the error I get when I try to create a folder on the sd card.
PS: This works for internal storage

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/1EFF-130C/Music/2020' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Comment: why don't you use, Flutter Permission package? https://pub.dev/packages/permission#-example-tab-

Comment: @snishalaka I just tried requesting the permission with the plugin above with the same result when writing to the sd card.

Comment: this may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micro SD cards are read only on modern Android devices.

Only one app specific directory is writable.

On Android Q+ the card is not even readable except for that directory.

You can however use SAF for full access.