# cannot access my storage in flutter in a real android device after installing the apk

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I access to my internal storage and camera in release mode with intellij idea. But when I generate the apk and deploy in a real android device it does not work.

Can you help me please?

This is my android manifest. When I want to access to the camera or the storage or googlemaplocation. It does nothing.

Thanks

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lesvoisins.app.simo.rafik.lesvoisins_flutterV2">
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="lesvoisins_flutterV2"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting permission to the external storage (file\_provider plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin)

Comment: yes, it does ask user to access the storage. But on more time it does not work on a real device

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens?

Comment: it does nothing. For information I use permission_handler for requesting permission