# How to save File in Downloads folder in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my flutter application I can create a pdf file, then I want to save it in Download folder.
I'm trying to achieve this goal with path_provider package, but I can't.

This is the sample code from flutter's cookbook, If I use it I don't get any error, but I don't find the file either.

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File file2 = File("${directory.path}/test.txt");
await file2.writeAsString('TEST ONE');
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: What if this case is for flutter web ?

Comment: Never used before, but file_saver package seems to be a good solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To find the correct path please use [ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage).
You will need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

on Android 10 you need this in your manifest

```
<application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

on Android 11 use this instead

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Remember to ask for them using **permission_handler**

I leave you my code:

```
  static Future saveInStorage(
      String fileName, File file, String extension) async {
    await _checkPermission();
    String _localPath = (await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))!;
    String filePath =
        _localPath + "/" + fileName.trim() + "_" + Uuid().v4() + extension;

    File fileDef = File(filePath);
    await fileDef.create(recursive: true);
    Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    await fileDef.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  }
```

Comment: `ext_storage` is discontinued - any good alternatives available?

Comment: any alternatives?

Comment: Hi, is this work on both android and iOS?

Comment: path_provider seems like a good alternative: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Comment: @AndrePerkins Unfortunately Download directory is not supported at the moment

Comment: This lib no longer maintained, avoid use it

Answer (score 9):

Android 11 changed a lot of things with its emphasis on scoped storage.  Although /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files is one of the directory paths given by the path_provider pkg, you won't be able to see files saved in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files just using any run-of-the-mill file application (Google Files, Samsung My Files, etc.).

A way to get around this (although it only works on Android) is to specify the "general" downloads folder as shown below.

```
Directory generalDownloadDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
```

if you write whatever file you are trying to save to that directory, it will show up in the Downloads folder in any standard file manager application, rather than just the application-specific directory that the path_provider pkg provides.

Below is some test code from an app I'm building where I save a user-generated QR code to the user's device.  Just for more clarity.

```
//this code "wraps" the qr widget into an image format
                          RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext!
                              .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
                          //captures qr image 
                          var image = await boundary.toImage();

                          String qrName = qrTextController.text;
                          
                          ByteData? byteData =
                              await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
                          Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

                          //general downloads folder (accessible by files app) ANDROID ONLY
                          Directory generalDownloadDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download'); //! THIS WORKS for android only !!!!!! 

                          //qr image file saved to general downloads folder
                          File qrJpg = await File('${generalDownloadDir.path}/$qrName.jpg').create();    
                          await qrJpg.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

                          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: ' $qrName QR code was downloaded to ' + generalDownloadDir.path.toString(), gravity: ToastGravity.TOP);
```

Comment: This worked like magic. Thank you

Comment: does it needs storage permission?

Comment: I have a problem, when I reinstall my app it says that this directory already exists, but why with getApplicationDocumentsDirectory sais that it doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 1):

You want [`getExternalStorageDirectories`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getExternalStorageDirectories.html). You can pass a parameter to specify the downloads specifically:

```dart
final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectories(type: StorageDirectory.downloads)).first!;

File file2 = File("${directory.path}/test.txt");
await file2.writeAsString('TEST ONE');
```

If you're using null safety you don't need the bang operator:

```dart
final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectories(type: StorageDirectory.downloads)).first;

File file2 = File("${directory.path}/test.txt");
await file2.writeAsString('TEST ONE');
```

Comment: I've tried to print the path and I think that's correct:
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files/Download" 
but I can't find the file, any ideas?

Comment: @EmanueleVinci You probably have an exception you ignore somewhere. You likely didn't give the permission to write to external storage. See this so answer for how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571167/13250142. You need both a permission in the manifest and at runtime. This is a guess though so please provide more detail as to what you've done to find the file, output from the code you're running, anything you've tried to solve it(e.g. immediatly reading back the file you just wrong in your dart code).

Comment: Half-solved the problem! I have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>, I ask correctly the permission, but the problem is that with Android 11 you need 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.
Anyway, the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files/Download"  is not accessible from the Files application. Any ideas?

Comment: @EmanueleVinci What is the *exact* error.

Comment: The exact problem is that Android 11 uses this new permission to write on storage (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), you don't get any exception, no message, anything... I've tried your code on another phone with Android 9 and it works!
Now to test it on my Android 11 phone I need to understand how to save in the Download folder

Comment: @EmanueleVinci https://stackoverflow.com/a/63024473/13250142

Comment: You cant use  getExternalStorageDirectories as that saves it to the app directory. as Emanuele commented with his path print statement. "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files/Download". Anything in that com.my.app folder wont be accessible from the users stand point like file explorer. I'm still trying to figure out how to save to the downloads folder myself and am not finding any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading file in Downloads folder, here are examples:

```
// Save multiple files
DocumentFileSave.saveMultipleFiles([textBytes, textBytes2], ["text1.txt", "text2.txt"], ["text/plain", "text/plain"]);

//Save single text file
DocumentFileSave.saveFile(textBytes, "my_sample_file.txt", "text/plain");

//Save single pdf file
DocumentFileSave.saveFile(pdfBytes, "my_sample_file.pdf", "appliation/pdf");

//Save single image file
DocumentFileSave.saveFile(imageJPGBytes, "my_sample_file.jpg", "image/jpeg");
```

More details of library here:
https://pub.dev/packages/document_file_save_plus