# How can I show the user the file that he just downloaded?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I used `Dio` to download a file as following:

```
final dio = Dio();
final Directory appStorageDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
await dio.download(
    url,
     "${appStorageDirectory.path}/file.pdf",
 );
```

Works and the pdf file is at:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files
```

But currently nothing happens that indicates a (successful/failed) download. I could alert some notification in the app that it was successful but I am used to something like a push notification that something was downloaded and clicking on that notification opens the file with whatever PDF reader of the device. How is this possible with flutter? Or 'at least' open it immediately when the download is finished?

Also that path is not easy to access for a user. Is it possible to save it in the more visible Downloads or Documents folder? `path_provider` does not seem to have a function for that so I assume it is not trivial to do for both android and iOS?

Comment: maybe this tutorial might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tfBflFUO7s&ab_channel=JohannesMilke

Comment: This answer will help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759809/how-to-save-file-in-downloads-folder-in-flutter

Answer (score -1):

```
final tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final splitPath = tempDir!.path.split("/");
log(tempDir.path);
String path = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
path += "${splitPath[i]}/";
}
log(path);
download(pdfLink,"${path}Download/$fileName");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).