# Flutter Android how to save File into download folder

Tags: android, flutter, file, download

Can you help me in Flutter how to save file into public download folder or any my app name folder.

i have tried but it's return Operation not permitted error.

Comment: Try looking at [How to save File in Downloads folder in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759809/how-to-save-file-in-downloads-folder-in-flutter)

Comment: I have checked but in above link used library is not available now.