# Store files from flutter application to external storage

Tags: flutter, dart, android-external-storage

Is it always safe to use the path "/storage/emulated/0/{MY APP NAME}" to store the files ?

I Want to store files in the external storage of the android device and I want to store it in a folder named after the app name this folder needs to be located in the external storage.

Comment: PLease check this you need to add external read/write permission -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the package `path_provider` https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install?

It comes with the methods `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` which might be what you are looking for. As far as I know different os types are automatically considered as well.

Comment: It returns '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.{APPNAME}/files'
I could extract the part before the directore "Android" but I wanna make sure it will be stable regardless of the device

Answer (score 0):

try the same package of ext_storage named android_external_storage its the same concept putting the downloaded data for example to the download folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40504#issuecomment-660615955).

The `directory` an app can access on sdcard looks like `/storage/1718-0217/Android/data/com.example.app_name/files`. You can get this with the code below.

```
(await getExternalStorageDirectories())?[1].path;
```

One app should only access some restricted directories on sdcard. Or you should use `Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()`, it is strongly restricted and always return false.

Fortunately, per-app directories can also be scanned by other services such like `media`.