# In Flutter, how to save a camera image to a folder like DCIM?

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera

Out of my league but I've put together the bones of a camera app (actiually MS Copilot did it).

Edit: A screenie of the app in action:
[image]

The last issue is to have the photo saved where I want it to go, e.g. "Internal shared storage/DCIM/AppTestPhotos".

The immediately related code:

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
    onPressed: () async {
      final XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
      String filePath = photo.path;
      print('File path from photo.path: $filePath');

      await Gal.putImage(filePath);
      print('Image saved at: $filePath');
    },
  ),
```

Using the default path from the XFile, the file path is indicated to be:

`/data/user/0/com.example.cam_test_2_one_screen/cache/CAP555419134659270816.jpg`
...which shows up in the "Internal shared storage/Pictures" Folder on the phone. I've tried amending the path to get it to show up in "Internal shared storage/DCIM/AppTestPhotos" but with no luck.

[image]

[image]

Any thoughts about how to get this to work? So close it seems.

Since it's not too long, here's the full main.dart file:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:gal/gal.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}

class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CameraScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraScreen({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  late CameraController controller;
  bool showFocusCircle = false;
  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Take a picture')),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapUp: (details) {
          _onTap(details);
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(child: CameraPreview(controller)),
            if (showFocusCircle)
              Positioned(
                top: y - 20,
                left: x - 20,
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
        onPressed: () async {
          final XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
          String filePath = photo.path;
          print('File path from photo.path: $filePath');

          await Gal.putImage(filePath);
          print('Image saved at: $filePath');
        },
      ),
      // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //   child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
      //   onPressed: () async {
      //     final XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
      //     final Directory? extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      //     if (extDir != null) {
      //       final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/DCIM/AppTestPhotos';
      //       await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
      //       final String filePath = '$dirPath/${DateTime.now()}.jpg';
      //       await photo.saveTo(filePath);
      //       print('Picture saved at: $filePath');
      //     }
      //   },
      // ),

      // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //   child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
      //   onPressed: () async {
      //     final XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
      //     final Directory? extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      //     if (extDir != null) {
      //       final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/AppTestPhotos';
      //       await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
      //       final String filePath = '$dirPath/${DateTime.now()}.jpg';
      //       await photo.saveTo(filePath);
      //       print('Picture saved at: $filePath');
      //     }
      //   },
      // ),

      // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //   child: Icon(Icons.camera),
      //   onPressed: () async {
      //     final XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
      //     print('Picture saved at: ${photo.path}');
      //   },
      // ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onTap(TapUpDetails details) async {
    if (controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showFocusCircle = true;
      x = details.localPosition.dx;
      y = details.localPosition.dy;
      double fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      double cameraHeight = fullWidth * controller.value.aspectRatio;
      double xp = x / fullWidth;
      double yp = y / cameraHeight;
      Offset point = Offset(xp, yp);
      await controller.setFocusPoint(point);
      setState(() {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).whenComplete(() {
          setState(() {
            showFocusCircle = false;
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
}

Future<void> _requestStoragePermission() async {
  final status = await Permission.storage.request();
  print('Permission status: $status');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Here is what I did to save the photo to the DCIM folder on Android

- It might not work with the latest Android version
- Check Permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

##### Here is the result

[image]

##### The code snippet

```dart
        FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
          onPressed: () async {
            final XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
            Uint8List captureImage = File(photo.path).readAsBytesSync();

            String _directory = '';
            if (Platform.isIOS) {
              _directory = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
            } else {
              /// It might not work with latest Android version
              /// Check Permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
              _directory = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM';
            }
            final path = '$_directory/captured${const Uuid().v1()}.png';
            final imagePath = await File(path).create();
            await imagePath.writeAsBytes(captureImage);

            await Gal.putImage(path);
            print('Image saved at: $path');
  
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for this Sowat. I've added:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
to AndroidManifest.xml which I guess covers "Check Permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE". I'm currently on Android 10 BTW.   The compiler is giving telling me: Undefined class 'Uint8List'. How might I fix that?

Comment: just import this package a built-in one, import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Comment: Thank you - that issue fixed! I had a permissions error and added code to deal with that. I got the permissions pop-up on my phone which I accepted but I still get a permissions error on the line: final imagePath = await File(path).create();" which reads: "Exception has occurred.
PathAccessException (PathAccessException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/captured986d04c0-01cd-1f1c-80d1-fdd70a4d3f47.png' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13))".  Any thoughts?

Comment: In the file AndroidManifest.xml, make sure to add this line android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" inside <application tag. See this for further info: [Getting permission to the external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin)

Comment: Oh man, it worked!! I've spent three days of my free time battling over this. I really can't thank you enough - I think the rest of the app will be okay. I'll edit my post with a clear solution for others. You're on my Hero list. :)